# Blazor State with using Fluxor: ActionSubscriber or SubscribeToAction what is better to use?

Tags: .net, blazor, fluxor

I'm novice with using Blazor and Fluxor, and I trying to deside what is better to use

IActionSubscriber - manually inject, subscribe and unsubscribe

or

inherit FluxorComponent - and use the ActionSubscriber

What is the best solution?
What is benefits and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from `FluxorComponent` has a couple of advantages, in that you don't need to manually call `StateHasChanged` all the time and you don't have to inject the `IActionSubscriber`, as it in included for free, and you don't have to remember to unsubscribe on disposing the component.

Functionality-wise, I don't think there's any difference, except that the `FluxorComponent` takes care of some work for you.

The only disadvantage I can think of is if inheriting from `FluxorComponent` keeps you from inheriting from another base component class.

As for myself, I just inherit from `FluxorComponent` and go. It's working very well.

Answer (score 1):

Descending from FluxorComponent will mean your component automatically subscribes to `StateChanged` on any `IState<T>` property - when triggered it will call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged` to ensure the UI is updated.

`IActionSubscriber` isn't meant for determining when to update the UI, but to allow the UI to catch data that doesn't get reduced into the store.  For example, an editable DTO from a server API for the current page to edit.